# Remove a whole line beginning with a pattern occurring anywhere after another pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, string, gawk

How can I remove any line beginning with `---` occurring in any line number after a line containing `# Match` (the first occurrence in any line number)?

---

EDIT:

The relationship between `#Match` with the lines starting with `---` is that the later can exist before or after `#Match` but it should be removed only if it exists after `#Match`. –

Sample Input

```
hello

this is sample
--- sdafasdf
adsafasf
asfas
fasf

#Match
this is sample
adsafasf
asfas    dafasf
------ lots of fun
---- test

adsfasf****
```

Expected Output

```
hello

this is sample
--- sdafasdf
adsafasf
asfas
fasf

#Match
this is sample
adsafasf
asfas    dafasf

adsfasf****
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, i just created this text.txt. If your file contents are different, then let us know.

```
bash-4.1$ cat test.txt
#Match
---- test
hello
#Match
this is sample
adsafasf
asfas
fasf
#Match
------ funny
------ lots of fun
#Match
dafasf
adsfasf

bash-4.1$ awk '/#Match/ {flag=1} flag && /^---/ {flag=0;next} 1' test.txt
#Match
hello
#Match
this is sample
adsafasf
asfas
fasf
#Match
------ lots of fun
#Match
dafasf
adsfasf
```

Comment: P.s, just informing that question is revised now, and you need update your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -e '/#Match/ {n; /^---/d; }' infile
```

The `n` command is reading the next line of input into the pattern space and `/^---/d` deletes that line if it starts with `---` only when previous line matched with `#Match`.

Answer to the **revised question**:

```
sed -e '/#Match/,$ { /^---/d; }' infile
```

Comment: Hi did you try it on the sample input? Surprisingly, I didn't succeed with your answer.

Comment: of course I tested. double check your pattern `#Match` if that exist in your file. If doesn't work, then please **edit** your question and add how do you tried and what you are getting (avoid saying `doesn't work` word only instead of details )

Comment: Hi could you please explain what is the use of `$` here?

Comment: in `sed` if it's outside substitution command, means `end of file`, in substitution if come means `end of line`

Comment: For a minor modification to the question should I ask it separately. `Remove a whole line beginning with a pattern (and the next line) occurring anywhere before another pattern`

Comment: don't know what you want exactly but maybe `sed -e '/#Match/ {N; /^---/d; }' infile` is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
awk '/#Match/,EOF {if (/^---/) next} 1' file
```

Starting with a line matching `#Match` until the variable `EOF` will become true (which will never happen, thus = end of input stream), skip the actual line if it matches three (or more) dashes at the beginning.

Comment: We prefer answers to include an explanation. Compare to αғsнιη’s answer.